A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction Required array size too large
I am getting this error while I am building APK.
These are error log:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> Required array size too large

I have tried the following methods
1. `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx10240m`
2. Tried to invalidate cache and restart android studio

but these dosen't work for me, How should I solve it, help!!


check if there are large sized Assets like image,audio,video files or any other unwanted files,do rebuild project once.
